# Setting the mac task bar menu with pyqt4 and then applying cx_freeze

Tags: python, macos, pyqt4, python-3.4, cx-freeze

I have a gui that has a mac task bar menu, see below:
[image]

The first 3 items on the menu were created using QtDesigner and their sub items and actions connect fine. I created the extra "file" dynamically to see if this would fix the problem. This menu appears exactly the same when I build it using `python3 setup.py build` and then run the executable produced.
When I produce a mac app using `python3 setup.py bdist_mac` however this menu doesn't appear, and instead I just get:

[image]

So I'm wondering why this occurs and if there's any files I'm missing in order to have the app pick up my menu. I'm guessing I need to generate qt_menu.nib which I think is where menu actions are meant to be stored, but I can't find how to generate that from the designer.

Using Python 3.4, latest version of cx_freeze, Mac OS X Yosemite and PyQt4.

Comment: It might be sufficient to just copy in qt_menu.nib; I think it's just a stub file of some kind, not a description of your specific menu structure. I forget where you find it and where it should go, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure why this wasn't working, or why my method fixed it, but I did 2 things to prevent the menu messing up:
1. I had been loading another main window before loading this one which was a smaller setup window. I now load this only when needed.

2. I was applying a stylesheet. For some reason whenever I apply that now the menu doesn't work. Again, clueless as to why.